# Add a slug in URL

Tags: vue.js, iis, vue-router

I'm hosting a Vue SPA in IIS.

I'm using VueRouter, and in my routes I have:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
    { path: '/customers', name:'customers', component: Customers },
    { path: '/qadcustomers', name:'qadcustomers', component: QadCustomers },
    { path: '/customer/:id?', name:'customer', component: Customer, props: true },
    { path: '/qadcustomer/:id?', name:'qadcustomer', component: QadCustomer, props: true },
    { path: '/import', name:'import', component: Import },
];
```

In the web server, I'm putting the files inside the directory: `inetpub/wwwroot/dev/myapplication`

What I would like to happen is that the application is accessed at:

`https://myserver/dev/myapplication/` <-- This will go to Home

`https://myserver/dev/myapplication/customers` <-- This will go to Customers

`https://myserver/dev/myapplication/qadcustomers` <-- This will go to QadCustomers

What happens now is that all my page is at `https://myserver/customers`, or `https://myserver/qadcustomers`. How do I add the slug `/dev/myapplication/` to the URL?

When this application goes to test server, the slug would be `/test/myapplication`, and in production it's going to be `/regionaloffice/myapplication`.

Comment: try to use the base option in the constructor https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks! Didn't know there is the 'base' option. I ended up using that, works perfect

Comment: posted the suggestion. If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the base option in the constructor:

type: string

default: "/"

The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under /app/, then base should use the value "/app/"

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#linkactiveclass

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Nested Routes - Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/dev/myapplication',
      component: MyApplication,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'route1',
          component: Route1
        },
        {
          path: 'route2',
          component: Route2
        }
...
```

It will add the `/dev/myapplication` prefix for all routes.

So your routes will looks like this:

- `/dev/myapplication/route1`
- `/dev/myapplication/route2`
- `/dev/myapplication/route3`